# Program stuck when calling my logbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to make a logbox in a other cs, but when i call the logbox to add text to it, nothing happends, no error, no text, nothing and the console shows that 3 threads stopped.

Here is the logbox:

```
public void loginfo(string text)
    {

        if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            this.CreateHandle();
        }

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{                                       
              logbox.AppendText(text + Environment.NewLine);      
        });

    }
```

Calling it:

```
commands.CreateCommand("ping").Do(async (e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await e.Channel.SendMessage("Pong");
                mainform.loginfo("I am a string!");
            }
            catch (Exception a)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
            }
        });
```

I call the logbox from another cs file. I get the box trough this line

```
Mainform mainform = new Mainform();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It probably has something to do with the fact that you're calling `.Invoke` which could well be deadlocking if your command **isn't** running on a background thread. If you put a breakpoint after `mainform.loginfo(` call, does it get hit?

Comment: @Clint It does get hit, but i cant move my mainform in the meanthime...

Comment: [This MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) says : "If the method that the async keyword modifies doesn't contain an await expression or statement, the method executes synchronously. A compiler warning alerts you to any async methods that don't contain await, because that situation might indicate an error. See Compiler Warning (level 1) CS4014."

Comment: @xVanjaZ can we see the signature of `SendMessage()`?